# Magento static block loading order

Tags: magento

Our magento home page consists of 5 static blocks. Each static block contains images and videos. Can we order blocks load by order. For example first block has video, but it loads last after loading all other blocks which contains images.

Comment: It is not issue with Order by Static Block. Home page load with all 5 static block in order which you placed. But Video static block size is large that's why it takes time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest that do not add those all 5 blocks in Home page, add only one that you want loaded first. And then write JavaScript/JQuery to fetch static blocks one by one by ajax request and append in your container.